# Hibernate - ThreadLocal<EntityManager> vs EntityManager per operation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, thread-local

I use Hibernate 5.1.0.Final, Guice, Jersey. I have HibernateModule which creates `EntityManagerFactory` and manages `EntityManager` instances:

```
public class HibernateModule extends AbstractModule {

    private static final ThreadLocal<EntityManager> ENTITY_MANAGER_CACHE = new ThreadLocal<EntityManager>();

    @Provides @Singleton
    public EntityManagerFactory provideEntityManagerFactory(@Named("hibernate.connection.url") String url, 
        @Named("hibernate.connection.username") String userName, 
        @Named("hibernate.connection.password") String password,
        @Named("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto") String hbm2ddlAuto,
        @Named("hibernate.show_sql") String showSql) {

        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.postgresql.Driver");
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.url", url);
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.username", userName);
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.password", password);
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.pool_size", "1");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hbm2ddlAuto);
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", showSql);
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.use.query_cache", "false");
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "false");

        return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("db-manager", properties);
    }

    @Provides
    public EntityManager provideEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {

        EntityManager entityManager = ENTITY_MANAGER_CACHE.get();

        if (entityManager == null || !entityManager.isOpen()) 
            ENTITY_MANAGER_CACHE.set(entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager());

        entityManager.clear();

        return entityManager;
    }
}
```

`entityManager.clear()` is used to clear persistence context and force to query up-to-date data from a dabatase. `GenericDAO` receives injected `EntityManager` from HibernateModule. Main methods:

```
public class GenericDAOImpl<T> implements GenericDAO<T> {

    @Inject
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    private Class<T> type;

    public GenericDAOImpl(){}

    public GenericDAOImpl(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(T entity) {
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    @Override
    public T find(Long entityId) {
        return (T) entityManager.find(type, entityId);
    }
}
```

Previously I have tried to implemented a solution which provides new `EntityManager` on every DB operation but it lead to some side effects like "detached entity passed to persist".

Is it good practice to reuse `EntityManager` from `ThreadLocal<EntityManager>`? Are there any potential drawbacks of this implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work correctly. Spring Framework is using the `ThreadLocal` class for the `EntityManager`. From reference:

> Spring makes it easy to create and bind a Session to the current
>   thread transparently

You should remember about JPA hints, `PersistenceContextType` and `FlushModeType` if you want to re-use EntityManager instance.